Why doesn't this discharge hose fit the stem inside this dehumidifier?
I am trying to attach a discharge hose to a kenmore dehumidifier.   Model number 580.54501800.
In the picture, the red arrow points to the discharge adapter, the other end of which connects to a garden hose.  The blue arrow is the stem where the water comes out.  As you can see, the stem is far too small to properly connect to the discharge adapter. I am certain this is the adapter that came with the unit; it us the only one we have ever owned.  Is there some fitting I am missing that would make these two mate correctly?  What are some workarounds if not?


The pic is dark so details aren't visible.    Perhaps there should be an "O-ring" on the black plastic part shown at the blue arrow,   I  imagine the water isn't under pressure, so a light seal is all that is needed.  The black part goes into the white part, correct?

The translucent white part has a double ring, which could indicate it's supposed to have a retaining clip holding it in place. Will it move toward the black part, is there any slack? The retaining clip may have worn out and broken, a new one proper one could be found or a suitable stand-in made out of some thin metal.

find a clear plastic tube that fits over the black part.

It looks to me like the discharge tube/hose was originally inside the adapter and has possibly retracted with age. The condensate drain is not under pressure. Therefore a properly secured, snug fit between the adapter and tube/hose should be adequate. I would suggest trying to rejoin them by slipping the drain tube into the adapter, if it will reach, and glue it in place. If it won't reach, then get some pipe or a fitting to make it reach. I don't have much experience with dehumidifiers but I do have experience with both automotive and residential HVAC condensate drains.
